# how to download files from google cloud bucket to local windows machine? Please give me example

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I tried to run below command but did not worked for me.
**gsutil -m cp gs://bkname/*.* c:/Download/**

Answer (score 1):

`gsutil cp gs://bucketname/filename c:/Download/` it works for me.

And make sure your account has right authorize to access bucket.